# Как найти какие коммиты были замерджены определенным merge comitoм

Tags: git

Я могу найти какому коммиту принадлежит мердж коммит используя

```
git rev-list hash1..master --ancestry-path
```

который вернет список коммитов в котором последний в списке является мердж коммитом коммита hash1. Могу ли я так же найти но только в обратную сторону, имея hash мердж коммита узнать при мердже каких коммитов он создался, к примеру я на ветке dev сделал три коммита и замерджил в master, в этом случае создается merge commit, и вот по hash merge commita хотелось бы найти эти три коммита.

```
git show -s --pretty=%P 460f49a3
```

показывает два коммита, первый из которых это послединй коммит из  этих трех коммитов(если брать по предыдущему примеру) а второй это коммит который никак не относится к этим коммитам

Comment: Не очень понятен вопрос.  Что нужно уздать?`git show hash` покажет список родительских коммитов.

Comment: @alexey-ten обновил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо что-то типа `git log HEAD^@ ^HEAD^`?

```
$ git log --oneline --graph 
*   f5a65e9 (HEAD -> master) Merge branch 'dev'
|\  
| * 9028190 (dev) dev3
| * c536333 dev2
| * f5183d3 dev1
* | 5572736 m3
|/  
* 9334130 second
* 26ceff9 init

$ git log --oneline --graph HEAD^@ ^HEAD^
* 9028190 (dev) dev3
* c536333 dev2
* f5183d3 dev1
```

Answer (score 1):

Простой командой `git log <merge_hash>~1..<merge_hash>`, например `git log  bc3372~1..bc3372`